# Jquery Resizable reduce DIV height to less than default value(i.e. reduce minHeight to about 1px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with Jquery UI Resizable feature.

I am using Jquery resizable to resize a div to different width and height.
it is working good, but when i try to reduce the height to a very low number, it is not reducing less than a certain aspect ratio

`

```
    $( 'divname' ).resizable({
        minHeight: 1
        });
```

`
In the above code eventhough i try to give 1 pixel as the minHeight, I am not able to resize the div less than 10px. Please help with the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set minHeight upto 10 not below that.

Go throught this https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-minHeight

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
minHeight: 150
});
```